# Shimano 105 - double chainring on triple chainset?

Tags: shimano, chainring

I ordered a middle chainring (39T) to change on my 105 5703 chainset. I didn't realise until it arrived that it specifies it is for a double chainset. Does this mean it will not fit on the triple? I suppose I could try it and see, but it is still packed so it could be exchanged.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [service instructions for the Shimano FC-5703](http://www.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/SI/105/SI_1M30A/SI-1M30A-003-ENG_v1_m56577569830702207.pdf), this crank is a 50D/39D/30T tooth pattern.

The 2 upper rings are "double" with only the 30t identified as a triple ring.

[image: FC-5703 Service Instructions]

This is not the case with all triple cranks, but with yours, that should be the correct chainring.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I decided to try it beforehand anyway as I needed to use the bike. It fits and works perfectly.